# Consumir SOAP en Asp.net Core 2

Tags: soap, asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.

Tengo un SOAP que utilizo para Login de usuarios (Usuario, Password) que me debe retornar un 0 o un 1 en caso que la contraseña corresponda al usuario.

Soy algo nuevo en ASP.NET CORE, podrían apoyarme para implementarlo?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using LoginServices;
using icmcore.Models;

namespace icmcore.Controllers
 {
     public class LoginController : Controller
{


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string rpe, string password)
    {

        var cliente = new wsLoginSoapClient();

        var dt = cliente.DirectorioPersonalAsync(rpe, password);
        var iCodigo = "";
        if (dt != null)
        {
            iCodigo = dt.Rows[0]["CodigoError"].ToString();
            if (iCodigo == "0")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "About");
            }
        }


        return View();
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcioniento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Comment: Gracias @RaulCacacho!!!, hice el recorrido.

Comment: en el else idCodigo = 1; y retornarlo en las cabeceras puede ser